# putty ssh mariaDB commend line create new db

Tags: database, mariadb

I have problem with find how to use mariaDB on putty with ssh. When I try create new database I have only

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create database cw_blog_ewa
    ->
```

and can do nothing insteade several command (like status, help, exit). Create database cw_blog_ewa won't work. And every tutorial I found was about mysql... So how to create database in mariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

ok, topic to close. I just fount that I have to end it by ;

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create database cw_blog_ewa;
```